# R Split strings into two columns based on TWO regular expressions

Tags: r, regex, split

I have some data that is structured something like this:

```
ID   Region            Value
1    Europe            8
2    Europe: Class 1   6
3    Asia: System 2    6
4    North America     7
5    Europe: System 1  5
6    Africa            7
7    Africa: Class 2   5
8    South America     9
9    Europe: System 1  3
10   Europe            7
```

What I want to do is create a new column called `Class` which adds instances of where "Class" AND "System" are mentioned in the `Region` column - if it's not clear what I mean, take a look at my expected output below. I know this can be done with the `separate` function but I think you can only specify one value for the separator part of the code. E.g. `sep = ": Class"` will only split instances that mention "class" but I also want to split any instances where "system" is mentioned too. Can this be done in one line of code, or do I need to do something a bit more complicated here? Here's how my final data should look:

```
ID   Region            Class  Value
1    Europe                   8
2    Europe            1      6
3    Asia              2      6
4    North America            7
5    Europe            1      5
6    Africa                   7
7    Africa            2      5
8    South America            9
9    Europe            1      3
10   Europe                   7
```

Please note, I want to remove any reference to "class" or "system" (including colons) from the `Region` column, and simply add the numerical value to a new `Class` column.

Comment: One solution that has just occurred to me, is to first replace all instances of " : System" with " : Class". That way, I can just separate by " : Class" and get the desired result. Would this be the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_extract` to extract the number and `str_remove` to drop the text that you don't want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Class = str_extract(Region, '(?<=(Class|System)\\s)\\d+'), 
         Region = str_remove(Region, ':\\s*(Class|System)\\s*\\d+'))

#   ID        Region Value Class
#1   1        Europe     8  <NA>
#2   2        Europe     6     1
#3   3          Asia     6     2
#4   4 North America     7  <NA>
#5   5        Europe     5     1
#6   6        Africa     7  <NA>
#7   7        Africa     5     2
#8   8 South America     9  <NA>
#9   9        Europe     3     1
#10 10        Europe     7  <NA>
```

`str_extract` extracts the number which comes after `'Class'`
or `'System'`. If these words are not present then it returns `NA`.

`str_remove` removes colon followed by zero or more whitespace (`\\s*`) followed by either `'Class'` or `'System'` and a number (`\\d+`).

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Region = c("Europe", "Europe: Class 1", 
"Asia: System 2", "North America", "Europe: System 1", "Africa", 
"Africa: Class 2", "South America", "Europe: System 1", "Europe"
), Value = c(8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 7L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: This works like a charm - thanks so much. I'm not a programmer, but I'd like to understand how/why this works. Is it that the first line of code creates a new column called `Class` that extracts from the `Region` column the regex specified? And that you used the "|" symbol to specify two expressions? The second line of code then removes those two expressions from the `Region` column. Also, duly noted about supplying the data in a reproducible format - will do this next time! :)

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer to include some more explanation about the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with base functions by just using strsplit with a regular expression that takes either `": System"` or `": Class"` as symbol:

```
splitted = strsplit(df$Region,"(: Class)|(: System)")
df$Region = lapply(splitted,FUN=function(x){x[1]})
df$Class = lapply(splitted,FUN=function(x){x[2]})
```

The result is:

```
> df
   ID        Region Value Class
1   1        Europe     8    NA
2   2        Europe     6     1
3   3          Asia     6     2
4   4 North America     7    NA
5   5        Europe     5     1
6   6        Africa     7    NA
7   7        Africa     5     2
8   8 South America     9    NA
9   9        Europe     3     1
10 10        Europe     7    NA
```